# HBase region split didn't happen when it exceeds the size

Tags: hadoop, split, hbase, region

The HBase region split is not happening when the existing region storefile size reached its configured size. In my case, the configured size is 10 GB but it is not split even when the size grows double or triple times. I could see the storefiles with 30 GB.

How to identify why the split didn't happen? What is the way to split it automatically?

Comment: What version of hbase do you use? And is there a custom split policy for your table?